# Sizing difference when page first loads

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my website, I am using some Bootstrap features to help with my CSS. I have a strange problem when I first load up the page, the positioning of some elements are off at first, but when I reload the page it is fixed. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

> Images below for reference.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="media post-react">
  <%= link_to post do %>
    <div class="media-left hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <%= image_tag("#{post.thumbnail_link}", :width => 320, :height => 180, class: "news-object") %>
    </div>

    <div class="media-body">
      <div id="media-heading">
        <h2 class="media-title align-left"><%= post.title %></h2>
        <p class="blog-index-date align-right"><span class="hidden-sm">Last updated: </span><%= post.updated_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %></p>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <p class="basic"><%= post.summary %></p>
      <p> </p>
      <p class="hype"><b>Read More</b></p>
      <p class="post-cat blog-index-date"><%= post.blog_category.name if post.blog_category_id.present? %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.media {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #404040;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.media-title { margin-top: 0px }
.media-body { position: relative }
.post-react {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: .45s, transform .45s ease;
  -moz-transition: .45s, transform .45s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .45s, transform .45s ease;
}

.post-react:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.01); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01); /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.01);
}

.blog-index-date {
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: #999999;
}

.post-cat {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 5px;
}

.news-object { border-radius: 2px }
```

**First Load:**
[image]

**After Refresh:**
[image]

This problem has been consistent over the past couple of weeks or so. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you watched the network stream to see if there's any delay in static file loading?

Comment: @isherwoodn No, I actually didn't think I could do that. How would I go about doing that? I'm running my website through a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 droplet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue seemed to be where I placed my stylesheet link in my code. In the first example, there where elements before it that may have caused it to take longer to load (google analytics, etc.).

The stylesheet I moved: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min", "application" %>`

After moving the link above google analytics, it seemed to fix the positioning issue.